# Creating connections in Xcode 4 prefixes names with _

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, iboutlet

When creating a new outlet in Xcode 4 it enters the necessary code like usual, but it prefixes a _ in the header file interface (but not in the properties):

```
UINavigationController *_mainNavController;
UIViewController *_rootView;
```

it also does this in the implementation file:

```
@synthesize mainNavController = _mainNavController;
@synthesize rootView = _rootView;
```

While I can of course use them with the prefixed _, it just makes my code messy. Am I doing something horribly wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can of course use them with the
>   prefixed _.

Why don't you use your properties (like `self.mainNavController`) instead of the backing ivars directly?

Read what Apple has to say about [using accessor methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW4):

> Sometimes it might seem tedious or
>   pedantic, but if you use accessor
>   methods consistently the chances of
>   having problems with memory management
>   decrease considerably. If you are
>   using retain and release on instance
>   variables throughout your code, you
>   are almost certainly doing the wrong
>   thing.

Properties encapsulate memory management code and thus reduce boilerplate.

> The only places you shouldn’t use
>   accessor methods to set an instance
>   variable are in `init` methods and
>   `dealloc`.

Also, the convention of prefixing backing ivars with `_` prevents you from accessing the backing ivars directly by mistake (and fail to retain an object, for example).

Comment: Oh it makes sense now! Thank you very much.